# D3 Force Layout: Collapse Subset of Child Nodes (Opacity Change)

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, force-layout

I am using a D3 force layout and trying to collapse child nodes whilst keeping the graph fixed, e.g. by simply changing them and their links' opacity. However, I am not trying to just collapse all nodes at once - I actually have an attribute in each node called "group", which can be 1,2 or 3.

When I click on a node, a tooltip appears with 3 buttons for each of these groups - upon clicking on the correct button, I would like the child node of that type to collapse, but all of its children (of all 3 groups) to collapse as well.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/annikamonari/3g4fqfa8/1/).

I have so far tried to create arrays of the node group ids and corresponding link IDs, and then use JQuery to hide those DOM objects but this didn't work:

```
function collapseNodes(node, collapseType, isCollapsed) {
    var collapseData = minimise(node, collapseType);
    var cNodes = collapseData.nodes,
        cLinks = collapseData.links;
    console.log(collapseData);
    var newClass = isCollapsed ? "uncollapsed" : "collapsed";

    cNodes.forEach(function(n) {
        d3.select(n).style("opacity", 0);
    });

    cLinks.forEach(function(l) {
        d3.select(l).style("opacity", 0);
    });
}

function minimise(node, assetMinType = "") {
    // Function to minimise a node
    var minNodes = [];
    var minLinks = [];

    if (node.group == 'asset') {
        node.children.forEach(function(child) {
            if (child.group == assetMinType)
                minimiseRec(child, node.id);
        });
    }
    else {
        minimiseRec(node, "");

        // We want to keep the top node and link
        minNodes.shift();
        minLinks.shift();

    }

    function minimiseRec(node, parentID) {
        minNodes.push("#" + node.id);
        minLinks.push("#parent_" + parentID + "_child_" + node.address);

        node.children.map(function(child) {
            minimise(child, node.id);
        });
    }

    return { nodes: minNodes, links: minLinks };
}
```

Does anyone know how best to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its only the opacity you wish to change this is fairly simple. I guess if you hide a nodes children you want to hide their childrens children and so on ?

First I set a variable `d.hiddenNode`. This is so I can toggle the opacity. I set it to false. And then on click function :

```
.on('click', function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    if(d.hiddenNode){
        hideChildren(d, false);
      d.hiddenNode = false;
    } else {
        hideChildren(d, true);
      d.hiddenNode = true;
    }

  })
```

Now because you want the childrens children etc to be hidden you need a recursive function like so. One that hides links and nodes ( I have commented to explain) :

```
function hideChildren(node, hide) {

  for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
    recurseChildren(node.children[i]); //loop through children to hide
  }

  function recurseChildren(node) {

    nodeEnter.each(function(d) { //go through all nodes to check for children
      if (d.index == node.index) { //if child is found
        d3.select(this).style('opacity', function(){ 
        return hide ? 0 : 1;        //toggle opacity depending on d.hiddenNode value
        }) //.remove(); 
      }
    })

    link.each(function(d) { //same with links
      if (d.source.index == node.index || d.target.index == node.index ) { //if source or target are hidden hide the link
        d3.select(this).style('opacity', function(){
        return hide ? 0 : 1;        
        }) //.remove(); 
      }
    })   

    if (node.children) { //if this node has children, call again but with their children
      for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
        recurseChildren(node.children[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/3g4fqfa8/2/

EDIT

For the pop up i just created a div that contains the 3 groups, 1,2,3 :

```
<div id='groupChoice'>
<div id='group1' class = 'group' onclick='hideGroup(1)'>1</div>
<div id='group2' class = 'group' onclick='hideGroup(2)'>2</div>
<div id='group3' class = 'group' onclick='hideGroup(3)'>3</div>
</div>
```

Set this to hidden in CSS :

```
.group{
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  border : 1px solid black;
}

#groupChoice{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

I have changed the logic slightly but this is the updated fiddle with commentary : http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/3g4fqfa8/3/

Theres some work that needs to be done with the links. I havent got enough time atm to finish it off, im sorry. But that should get you started.

Basically, when you click a node, pop up comes up, you chose a group to hide, they get hidden. Hit the same node again, chose a node to show. This was done super quick, so there's a lot wrong with it, but the basics are the so it should help :)

Comment: Im sorry i havent enough time to finish it off. The logic is quite simple, just check if the node belongs to the group you wish to hide and if it is hide it and its children